# error in registering command in laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel

i am trying to make my own command in laravel 5.0, but it generates the following error. i have registerd my command in kernel. following are my codes
//folowing error

```
  [ErrorException]
  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Console\Application::add() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Console\Command
  \Command, instance of App\console\Commands\qwork given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\queue_mail\vendor\laravel\framewo
  rk\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php on line 115 and defined
```

//my command qwork.php

```
<?php namespace App\console\Commands;
use DB;
use App\Commands\Command;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;

class qwork extends Command implements SelfHandling, ShouldBeQueued {

    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        DB::insert('insert into users (name, email) values (?, ?)', ['faran', 'ran.rana@gmail.com']);

    }

}


//then defining route by:

Route::get('/run', function()
{
    Artisan::queue('command:qwork');
});
```

Comment: What does class 'App\Commands\Command' extend?. The 'Application::add()' methods is expecting the first argument to be an instance of the class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command'. However, the provided first arg for add() was 'App\console\Commands\qwork'. Thus the error. We need to ensure the first argument is a class derived from 'Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command'.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
use App\Commands\Command;
```

with

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
```